# different repositories of different project in the same query

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with Entity Framework using generic repository pattern with DI (Ninject).

I have a main project that other sites connect to it. the main project has it's own domain repository which connect to the general tables in the db. each site that connect to it has also it's own domain repository which connect to it's own db tables. My problem is that when i try to do complex linq queries that combine both the site tables with the main project tables the code won't shout he cannot use two different dbcontext in the same query. so I have to divide my queries and pull the data from one repository table (ToList()) before I can use it in the other  repository tables. From where I look at it I cannot use the same DbContext for both repository because the main project comes as a Dll for the site project.

Comment: I retagged your question. By adding 'ninject' to the tags, hopefully one of the Ninject experts can explain to you how to configure Ninject to get a per web request for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You gave the answer yourself. You can't use multiple `DbContext` instances for a single query (which is quite obvious when you think about it). Instead use a single instance for all repositories in a single web request. Ninject has a [Per Web Request lifestyle](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope).

Comment: the problem is the main project repository comes as a dll for the site project.

Comment: Why is that a problem? All assemblies run in the same web application (in the same app domain)? Just configure this in the Composition Root of your application.

Comment: @mastha: It doesn't matter where your repository is declared. Simply repository wraps the context and context wraps the connection to database. If you want to make complex query all parts of the query must run on the same connection. If they don't your architecture is wrong and you must return to white board and design your application in another way to support per request context instancing with dependency injection of context into created repository instances.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka can you please give me an example of injection binding of the dbContext so it will be clearer? right now I am binding the repositories through ninject, but I don't explicitly resolve the DbContext in the ninject section(App_Start - under RegisterServices function). I just have a constructor for each repository and I Assign the DbContext as parameter. something like this:    public MyConstructor(DbContext context){ _context = context;}

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: by the way when I think about it, each project has it's own entity connection (different edmx file). So can it still be same context?